# TFS 2012 Web Access Assigning Default Area and Iteration Paths

Tags: workitem, tfs-workitem, tfs-web-access

I have an issue with TFS 2012. When ever a user creates a work item in TFS 2012, TFS is assigning the area path and iteration path to a default value of:

Area Path: Team Project\Sub Category 1\X
Iteration Path: Team Project\Sprint Y

Instead of making the users chose the area and iteration paths from the root nodes of:

Area Path: Team Project
Iteration Path: Team Project

However, this is only appearing in TFS Web access. I checked my work items and they do not have any code to set a default area or iteration path within the xml. Anyone know what might be the cause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Access uses the [Team's default area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh528603.aspx) (and sprint depending on where you add the work item) as it's default when creating workitems. This is meant to be a convenience.

You can edit the Web Access experience to show fields for this on the Quick Add bar by [updating the process template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh739073.aspx#quick_add).

Comment: Great, I didn't know that the new feature was introduced. Thanks for the info!

Comment: This is **so** not a "convenience".